# Show certain infowindows in Google Map array

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to be able to show certain infowindows on the page load. So rather than the user having to hover over them they'll already be loaded - however, I'd only like to do this on 2 out of the 4 markers in my array.

```
    var marker, i;
    var markers = [];
    var locations = [
        ['<div style="width: 170px;">Title1</div>', 50.794785, -1.116947, image],
        ['<div style="width: 190px;">Title2</div>', 50.797, -1.109, image],
        ['<div style="width: 120px;">Title3', 50.796928, -1.107119, '../images/map-pointer.png'],
        ['<div style="width: 150px;">Title4</div>', 50.794703, -1.117880, '../images/map-pointer.png']
    ];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
                    map: map,
                    icon: locations[i][3],
                    //visible: false,
                    zIndex: 10
                }); 

                /* Open marker on mouseover */
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                })(marker, i));
                markers.push(marker); // save all markers


            }               
            /* Change markers on zoom */
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                var zoom = map.getZoom();
                // iterate over markers and call setVisible
                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(zoom >= 15);
                }

                if (map.getZoom()>=15) {
                    flightPath.setMap(map)
                } else {
                    flightPath.setMap(null)
                }
            });
```

What I thought I might be able to do would be to add to the array a false/true at the end like so:

```
var locations = [
        ['<div style="width: 170px;">Title1</div>', 50.794785, -1.116947, image,true],
        ['<div style="width: 190px;">Title2</div>', 50.797, -1.109, image,true],
        ['<div style="width: 120px;">Title3', 50.796928, -1.107119, '../images/map-pointer.png',false],
        ['<div style="width: 150px;">Title4</div>', 50.794703, -1.117880, '../images/map-pointer.png',false]
    ];
```

And then some sort of IF statement like:

```
 if ((marker[i][4]) == true) {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
 }
```

It's not working for me but am I on the right track? Would this be how it would be done?

**EDIT**

So it's partially working.

This is what my for loop looks like currently:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3],
                //visible: false,
                zIndex: 10
            }); 

            /* Check to see if it should open */
            if ((locations[i][4]) == 'true') {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }

            /* Open marker on mouseover */
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
            markers.push(marker); // save all markers


        }
```

It's only doing one of my 'true's though - I'm assuming thats because I need multiple instances of infoWindow like the person below said.

**EDIT: Managed to do it - for those interested see below!**

Comment: What is "marker[i][4]"?  That doesn't look right.  Needs to be your locations array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it! For those interested:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
var markers = [];
var locations = [
    ['<div style="width: 170px;">Title1</div>', 50.794785, -1.116947, image,'true'],
    ['<div style="width: 190px;">Title2</div>', 50.797, -1.109, image,'true'],
    ['<div style="width: 120px;">Title3', 50.796928, -1.107119, '../images/map-pointer.png','false'],
    ['<div style="width: 150px;">Title4</div>', 50.794703, -1.117880, '../images/map-pointer.png','false']
];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
    map: map,
    icon: locations[i][3],
    //visible: false,
    zIndex: 10
    }); 

    /*  Open specific markers on page load */
    var infocontent = locations[i][0];        

    if ((locations[i][4]) == 'true') {
    var infwin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: infocontent});
    infwin.open(map, marker);
    }

    /* Open marker on mouseover */
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker); // save all markers

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
if ((locations[i][4]) == true)
```

more issues:

- currently the infowindow doesn't have any content(the content is set onmouseover). Instead of programmatically open the infowindow, trigger a mouseover on the marker:

```
    if ((locations[i][4])) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'mouseover');
    }
```

- it appears that you are using a single `google.maps.InfoWindow`-instance, you must use multiple instances when you want to have multiple InfoWindows open at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I go about making multiple infoWindows? Would it be var infowindow, i = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); ?